# Local notification and Open specific screen

Tags: model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uilocalnotification

when I get local notification I want to open my specific screen.
currently in my app i have used both navigation controller as well as model view controller so at the time of navigation controller, app is switching any view but when model controller exit . it is not opening the screen.
Plz suggest any solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
There are two way to launch app when notification comes.
```

1- app is running in background.then open specific screen like 
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:  (UILocalNotification *)notification
    {

```
   // write this line  
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];


}

in which controller class you are create notification.
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reloadTable)
                                             name:@"reloadData"
                                           object:nil];
   }

- (void)reloadTable
  {
     //  create object of that controller which your want to open.

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
     AddToDoViewController *cvc = (AddToDoViewController *)[sb    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddToDo"];

    [self presentModalViewController:cvc animated:YES];
```

}